# How does New-MigrationBatch work?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Does `New-MigrationBatch` create `New-MoveRequest` for each user internally?

Can somebody explain to me how `New-MigrationBatch` works internally?

Answer (score 0):

***New-MigrationBatch*** cmdlet is use to submit a new migration request for a batch of users. It helps to Move mailboxes to different databases in on-premises Exchange organizations.

Example to take input *from CSV* file:

```
#It creates a migration batch for a local move, where the mailboxes in the specified CSV file are moved to a different mailbox database. 
#This CSV file contains a single column with the email address for the mailboxes that will be moved. 
#The header for this column must be named EmailAddress.

$InputCSV="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Input.csv"
New-MigrationBatch -Local -Name MyFirstBatch -CSVData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($InputCSV)) -TargetDatabases MyLocalDB
Start-MigrationBatch -Identity MyFirstBatch
```

Note: You can use AutoStart in order to run batches automatically.

To create a migration endpoint for the on-premises Exchange server, and then uses that endpoint to create the migration batch.

```
$InputCSV="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FirstBatch.csv"
$Endpoint = New-MigrationEndpoint -ExchangeOutlookAnywhere -Name Endpoint -Autodiscover -EmailAddress user@domain.com -Credentials $Credentials
$StagedBatch1 = New-MigrationBatch -Name FirstBatch -SourceEndpoint $Endpoint.Identity -CSVData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($InputCSV))
Start-MigrationBatch -Identity $FirstBatch.Identity
```

For Further reference, Please visit [Technet--New-MigrationBatch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219166(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Hope it helps.